# XML External Entity injection in xsd upload

Tags: xml, security, owasp, xxe

I am uploading a xsd in my j2ee based web application  which is  genrating java classes and that is used later for processing. Uploading xsd has been identified as exploitable for XML External Entity injection. I searched lot of places and understood how it can be fixed for xml . But there no clarity on XSD
Let me know if somebody has any idea on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special for XSD here. An XSD document is just like any other XML document as far as this attack vector is concerned.

Comment: yes Michael. I realized it later after asking question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SchemaCompiler schemaCompiler = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
schemaCompiler.setDefaultPackageName(packageName);
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false); 
xmlInputFactory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isSupportingExternalEntities", false); 
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xsdFile));
try {
    schemaCompiler.parseSchema(xsdFile.toURI().toString(),xmlStreamReader);
} catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```